# How to get a GOOGLE Map image after providing set of locations?

Tags: android, google-maps-static-api

Currently i am using GOOGLE Static Map API. But My URL exceed the maximum characters that allocated for stranded URL. Are there any ways to do this without GOOGLE Static Map API?

Comment: What actually you want? A static map image for a certain lat, long or for set of Lat, lang?

Comment: @noman404 I want static map image for a certain lat, long.

Answer (score 1):

you can't get list of static maps by providing list of set of locations. That'll provide you JSON/XML response. To get a static map of a certain location i used below solution 4 years ago. I am not sure about any updated solution. have a look at this URL

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=LATITUDE,LONGITUDE&zoom=15&size=200x200&sensor=false
```

The url is the tricky part here, it actually returns a static image of the requested lat, lang. You can also specify the image size you want, here i used 200x200. Also you can use any ImageLoader i.e. Glide, picasso to load that image

```
public Bitmap getMapImage(double latitude, double longitude) {

    Bitmap bmp = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        java.net.URL mapUrl = new URL("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+latitude+","+longitude+"&zoom=15&size=200x200&sensor=false");

        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) mapUrl.openConnection();

        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());

        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

        inputStream.close();
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.toString());
    }

    return bmp;
}
```

Comment: Up to this point I have done. The thing is URL  exceed the maximum character limit.

Comment: where you get that maximum character limit?

Comment: Static Maps has an URL length limit of 8K characters. Do you really create so long URL?

Comment: I have tested this code and it's working properly also the url doesn't contain 8K characters

Comment: yes of course. the device(Taxi) update its location at every 10 seconds. After finish the trip i need to get a image of the root which the taxi went. these trips may be 4 hour maximum long. In that case the URL may exceed 8k characters.

Comment: @noman in my case the url will definitely exceed the limit. yes your code is okey for URLs which don't contain 8k characters.

Comment: So the problem with your URL not the static map. please ask the proper question. you have to optimize your URL.

Comment: Is there any way that i can do this without static map or with static map with long urls? Thats what i asked.